# python nested list and dicts, trouble accesing and setting

Tags: python, list, data-structures, dictionary

I am originally a c guy but recently I started doing some stuff in python.
The things that gives me trouble is the more advanced data structures in python.

I could do it all with multiple list like in c but that would just be boring right?

anyway here I have a data structure which is basically a list of dicts where the value field of the dict is another list of 2 key-value pairs:

```
clients = [
    {'client1':[{'test':'testvalue','status':'statusvalue'}]},
    {'client2':[{'test':'testvalue','status':'statusvalue'}]},
    {'client3':[{'test':'testvalue','status':'statusvalue'}]}
]
```

now I want to be able to acces the testvalue and statusvalue fields and modify or read them. based on the position in the list.

in pseudocode it would be something like:

```
for i in range(0,clients):
    getvalue(clients[i].'test')
    setvalue(clients[i].'test')

    getvalue(clients[i].'status')
    setvalue(clients[i].'status')
```

in the end I want to use this data structure to render a html page with jinja2

Comment: Why do you have lists at all here?

Comment: `clients` is not valid Python.

Comment: what do you mean clients is not valid? I use a list because I want to be able to iterate of it.

Comment: You can iterate over a dict too. I might see cause to have `clients` be a list, depending on how it's used and whether element order matters, but the inner data structures look like they should just be dicts instead of 1-element lists. Also, you're missing a bunch of commas between the elements of `clients`.

Comment: you forgot the commas in clients :-)

Comment: yes but dicts are unordered whereas lists arent. I need to be able to acces the structure in an ordered fashion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a start, in Python you should (almost) never iterate over `range(len(something))`. You iterate over `something`.

Secondly, your data structure is wrong. There's no point having a list of dicts, each dict containing a single key/value pair and each value consisting of a list with a single item. You should just have a dict of dicts: you can still iterate over it.

```
clients = {
    'client1':{'test':'testvalue','status':'statusvalue'},
    'client2':{'test':'testvalue','status':'statusvalue'},
    'client3':{'test':'testvalue','status':'statusvalue'},
}

for key, value in clients.iteritems():
    print value['test']
    value['test'] = 'newvalue'
```

Comment: but in this way, the list isn`t ordered anymore? I mean client1 wont be the first that gets printed all the time..

Comment: if you want to keep the dictionary with keys ordered, you need to get OrderedDict from collections.

Comment: but what is the advantage over using only dicts and me using lists with a combination of dicts?

Comment: @prgmjunkie: If the position of the entry is the thing you want to use to access it, rather than the `client1` name, it may be preferable to have `'client1'` be a value rather than a key: `clients = [{'name': 'client1', 'test': 'testvalue', 'status': 'statusvalue'}, {'name': 'client2', ...`

Comment: thank you I ended up doing exactly what you said. makes everything uniform also

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that you put a dictionary inside a list as the value for each client.

I think you may wish to re-configure your data structure as such:

```
clients = [
    {'client1':{'test':'testvalue','status':'statusvalue'}}
    {'client2':{'test':'testvalue','status':'statusvalue'}}
    {'client3':{'test':'testvalue','status':'statusvalue'}}
]
```

Therefore, you can begin iterating as such:

```
for client in clients:
    for k, v in client.iteritems(): #this unpacks client into 'client' (k) and {'val'...} (v)
        print v['test'] #this gets the value of test.
        v['test'] = 'some_new_value' #this sets the value of test.
```

Comment: yes you are correct. Because lists are ordered. I always want to first iteration to get the first I defined, and the second the second etc. This is because I want to render an html form it using jinja2 and I want the first item to be displayed first

Comment: Ah, ok, let me reconfigure my own answer then.